# How to select from mutiple tables with partial dependency?

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2, partial

I have two tables in my SQL Server 2008. One is the item list and the other is item flow like this:

Item table:

```
item_id   item_name
--------------------
      1       item1
      2       item2
      3       item3
```

and flow table:

```
date        item_id   qty
-------------------------
2014-10-15        1     5
2014-10-15        2     3
2014-10-16        1     7
2014-10-17        1     4
2014-10-17        2     2
2014-10-17        3     1
```

How can I keep select every data in item table with no record in flow table so I can get result like this:

```
date        item   qty
-----------------------
2014-10-15  item1    5
2014-10-15  item2    3
2014-10-15  item3    0
2014-10-16  item1    7
2014-10-16  item2    0
2014-10-16  item3    0
2014-10-17  item1    4
2014-10-17  item2    2
2014-10-17  item3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a combination of `cross join` and `left join`

```sql
SELECT dt.date, item.item_name, ISNULL(flow.qty,0)
FROM item CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT date from flow) dt
LEFT JOIN flow on item.item_id=flow.item_id and dt.date=flow.date
ORDER BY dt.date, item.item_name
```

this solution may have a more elegant alternative, perhaps you may find it later. =)